# MYSQL - Existe alternativa para o LIMIT nas subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, select-limit

Estou usando **MYSQL**.
Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
create table visita (
   id int,
   titulo_socio varchar(10),
   data_visita date,
   cidade_visitada varchar(50),
   status_visitacao varchar(50)
);
```

Um **exemplo de dados** para essa tabela:

```
id   titulo_socio   data_visita   cidade_visitada   status_visitacao

10   11111          2005-02-12    Goiania/GO        Sim
11   11111          2010-05-19    Marilia/SP        Sim
12   11111          2015-01-23    Brasilia/DF       Nao
13   22222          2014-01-02    Brasilia/DF       Sim
14   22222          2012-10-21    Goiania/GO        Nao
15   33333          2010-08-09    Marilia/SP        Nao
```

**Preciso de uma SQL que retorne somente a linha com data mais atual de cada sócio**, assim:

```
id   titulo_socio   data_visita   cidade_visitada   status_visitacao

12   11111          2015-01-23    Brasilia/DF       Nao
13   22222          2014-01-02    Brasilia/DF       Sim
15   33333          2010-08-09    Marilia/SP        Nao
```

Tô fazendo isso usando **subquery**, mas o **MYSQL não aceitou o LIMIT**:

```
SELECT titulo_socio, data_visita, cidade_visitada, status_visitacao from visita WHERE (titulo_socio, data_visita) IN (SELECT titulo_socio, max(data_visita) FROM visita GROUP BY titulo_socio LIMIT 500);
```

**Sem o LIMIT funciona**, mas preciso limitar porque a tabela tem mais de 30 milhões de tuplas e fica inviável a consulta.

Existe alguma outra forma alternativa de se conseguir esse resultado sem usar o LIMIT na subquery?

Valeu

Comment: Você pode fazer um agrupamento pela pk e ordenar pela data de modo descendente, serve?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Você poderia me dar um exemplo? Obrigado

Comment: Resolvi o mesmo problema nesse POST: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370267/recuperar-o-maior-valor-em-uma-coluna-de-acordo-com-a-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-segunda/370275