# Recuperar o maior valor em uma coluna de acordo com a repetição da segunda

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Boa noite a todos!

Eu tenho um sistema em minha empresa que registra um valor inteiro em uma tabela a cada momento do dia. Ele também registra a data e a hora em formato Datetime;

A tabela no banco está da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver na coluna data ele vai repetindo o a data. 
Eu preciso realizar uma consulta nesse banco MySQL onde retorne a maior quantidade por dia. Nesse caso acima a consulta teria que retornar da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!

Banco de dados: MySQL 5

Comment: Caso tenha ajudado lembre-se de marcar como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT MAX(QTD), DATA FROM TABELA GROUP BY DATA
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Gustavo! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Você não imagina como me ajudou rsrs

Mais uma vez obrigado